# after upgrade wifi icon missing

Tags: networking, configuration

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (didn't really want to, was perfectly happy on 10.10, but got tired of the constant warning that my distribution was no longer supported). After a recent install of updates the wifi icon on the top tool bar is missing. I need it back because Ubuntu keeps connecting to the wrong network and I cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than [installing `synaptic` from the Terminal and using it to install `network-maanger-gnome`](https://askubuntu.com/a/160982/22949), you can just install `network-manager-gnome` from Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or from the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome
```

That is, of course, assuming that the problem is that `network-manager-gnome` isn't installed (or was uninstalled).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install Synaptic package manager. Run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

in a Terminal, or install from the Ubuntu Software Center.

After installing, open it and type `network-manager-gnome` in the Quick filter box. Now tick on the small white box and click on "Apply". And restart your computer, then you are done.*